# Освобождение памяти локальной переменной

Tags: c++

Предположим, что функция возвращает некоторый экземпляр класса, статически определенный в теле функции как локальная переменная. Например так:

```
MyClass getMyClass(){
  MyClass myobject;
  return myobject;
}
```

Функция может вызываться много раз, соответственно в памяти будет возникать много копий объекта. Как следует освобождать выделенную память в таком случае?

Comment: >**статически** определенный в теле функции как **локальная** переменная

Это как? В коде ничего статического не наблюдаю. Покажите, пожалуйста, место, где Вы выделяете память, которую требуется освободить.

Comment: Я не выделяю память явно. Но MyClass object - это же объект, занимающий память. Что произойдет, если функцию вызывать много раз?

Comment: @DarkGenius Оно не статически. Оно автоматически, т.е. память выделяется в стеке, и при выходе из функции освобождается. Статически (в смысле Си и Си++ имеют описатель static и размещаются в секции данных).

Comment: Как объект освободится при выходе из функции, если я буду использовать результат, возвращенный функцией? Получается, результат нельзя использовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внутри Вашей функции объект будет создан на стеке. В момент выхода в строке с return произойдет следующее. Объект будет скопирован (или перемещен, если это с++11 и все правильно описано). Исходный объект будет удален. Возникает вопрос - а куда он будет скопирован?. Для этого нужно посмотреть в точку вызова этой функции. Она будет выглядеть где то так

```
MyClass mc = getMyClass(); // 1 случай
```

или так

```
mc = getMyClass(); // 2 случай
```

или даже так

```
getMyClass(); // 3 случай
```

с третим случаем все понятно, скорее всего объект даже не будет копироваться (просто некуда). Утечек памяти не будет.

Второй случай прост. У нас объект есть и есть объект, который возвращается с функции. Ваш конструктор копирования должен аккуратно перенести объект.

Первый случай интересен тем, что здесь возможны два варианта. В первом, будет создан объект и потом в него скопирован объект с функции. В втором - компилятор может догадаться, что объект нужно будет копировать, и выделить память под него сразу в нужном стеке (в стеке вызывающей функции). В этом случае вызываемая функция не будет выделять память в своем стеке, делать копирование и удаление. И иногда компилятор так и делает. Это известное узкое место и оно базируется на том, что Вы **гарантируете** компилятору, что конструктор копирования все правильно скопирует.

В каких случаях нужно делать свой конструктор копирования? Если Вы написали свой обычный конструктор - напишите и конструктор копирования/деструктор.
Когда нужно быть аккуратным с конструктором копирования? Если в коде конструктора есть вложенных классов или выделение памяти через new (или alloc/malloc и подобное. Это конечно не сильно приветствуется в с++ коде, но иногда бывает сложно без них).

Answer (score 0):

выделяйте память в методе при помощи new, возвращайте указатель, после использования delete'om очищайте (естественно за пределами метода)

Comment: Всегда стоит динамически выделять память? Просто объявлять объекты как в приведенной мной функции - это плохо?

Comment: Да нельзя так сказать, что плохо. Просто при возврате из getMyClass будет происходить копирование объекта. Если это устраивает -- то всё OK. А проблемы, о которых я писал, возникли бы, если бы Вы возвращали указатель на внутренний объект. Там была бы бяка

Comment: @DarkGenius
Еще вариант. Часто не возвращают указатель, а передают его, как параметр:

    class ObjectType { ... };

    void getObject( ObjectType **outPtr )
    {
        (*outPtr) = new ObjectType(...);
    }

    // ...Using
    ObjectType *obj = nullptr;
    getObject(*obj);